# Prepareforsegue with json populated cell

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am populating a UITableViewCell with json data this way

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("jsonCell") as! Celda
    var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
    cell.nombre1.text = dict["nombre"] as? String
    cell.nombre2.text = dict["calle"] as? String
    cell.id.text = dict["id"] as? String
    return cell
```

But I can't pass my data, what would be my prepareforsegue code if I want to pass the `id` text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have made some attempts and then posted your attempts. But here is an example...

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "Identifier"  {
        let navigationContoller = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navigationContoller.topViewController as! MyViewControllerToSegueTo
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let dataToPass = data[indexPath!.row]
        controller.recieveingVariable = dataToPass
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error `use of unresolved identifier data`. I guess it might be something relative to the `id` I want to pass

Comment: i just used `data` as a placeholder for whatever variable you want to pass along...  so yes you are getting that error because you never defined `data`

Comment: In your case, perhaps, store your `id` in a variable (or whatever data you want to pass along) and then set that variable  equal to `dataToPass` . Additionally, if you are not using a navigation controller then you can neglect the line that says `let navigationController =...` and just use `let controller = segue.destinationController as! MyViewController`

Comment: I am sorry but I'm new in coding, how can I store that json data in a variable?

Comment: simply set it equal to a variable that you create. example: `let myString = dict["calle"] as? String` .  Then you can pass along `myString` in prepareForSegeue

Comment: `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "templos"  {
            let navigationContoller = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let controller = navigationContoller.topViewController as! single_templo
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let myString = dict["id"] as? String
            let dataToPass = myString[indexPath!.row]
            controller.prueba = dataToPass
        }
    }
`

Comment: I am getting an error because of unresolved identifier dict, I don't think I have to create the variable here...

Comment: I assume you figured it out

Comment: Finally, I did. Thanks!